# Async Await deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, async-await

I'm working with the `Accelerometer` sensor on Windows Phone 8.1. I must access the UI from the `ReadingChanged` callback of the sensor. I also have a `DispatcherTimer` that, every two seconds, updates the `ReportInterval` of the sensor. The program blocks when the timer fires and try to set the ReportInterval of the Accelerometer. The example here below is a minimum executable example that reproduces the error.

```
namespace TryAccelerometer
{        
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Accelerometer acc;
        private DispatcherTimer timer;                
        private int numberAcc = 0;
        private int numberTimer = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            acc = Accelerometer.GetDefault();                                    
            acc.ReadingChanged += acc_ReadingChanged;

            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();            
        }

        async void acc_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
        {            
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                //HERE I WILL HAVE TO ACCESS THE UI, BUT FOR SAKE OF SIMPLICITY I WROTE AN INCREMENT
                numberAcc++;
            });
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            numberTimer++;            
            //PUT A BREAKPOINT HERE BELOW AND SEE THAT THE PROGRAM BLOCKS
            acc.ReportInterval = acc.ReportInterval++;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the deadlock happens. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't seen this on WP, but historically there have been initialization problems with some MS UI frameworks. Try accessing the `CoreWindow.Dispatcher` *before* calling `Accelerometer.GetDefault`. Some XAML frameworks create dispatchers on demand, and that may cause odd issues if `ReadingChanged` fires before the dispatcher loop starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm stumped.

`Dispatcher.RunAsync` shouldn't possibly cause a deadlock. Therefore, to find out where exactly the issue is, I rewrote your code on multiple lines:

```
async void acc_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var view = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView;

    var window = view.CoreWindow;

    var dispatcher = window.Dispatcher;

    await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { numberAcc++; });
}
```

The real culprit is `var window = view.CoreWindow;`. It's hard to explain why without seeing the WinRT source code, I guess there is some weird interaction between WinRT needing to switch to the UI thread to retrieve the reference to the window, and the `ReportInterval` property of the Accelerometer executing synchronously the `ReadingChanged` event.

From there, I can think of a few solutions:

1. Retrieve the dispatcher another way:

   ```
   async void acc_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
   {
       await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { numberAcc++; });
   }
   ```

   Of course, whether it's possible or not depends on your actual code.
2. Rewrite your code to use a `Timer` instead of a `DispatcherTimer`. I understand that you need to use the UI thread to retrieve the value of a textbox (or something like that), but if you use databinding (with or without the MVVM pattern), then you should be able to access the read the value of the bound property from any thread
3. Change the `ReportInterval` in another thread. Feels really hackish though.

   ```
   void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
   {
       numberTimer++;
       Task.Run(() => { acc.ReportInterval = acc.ReportInterval++; });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot apply your first solution cause my actual "this" is not a Control and maybe the third solution is a little bit tricky, but the second one is perfect. How did you debug it? I understand that you have broke the code in several lines, but then? Can you explain me how you understand that the problem was exactly at this line -->  "var window = view.CoreWindow;"

Comment: @superpuccio After you reproduce the deadlock, click on the "pause" icon of Visual Studio to break into the debugger, then use the tasks view (Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks) to see the callstack of each thread. Then double-click on the stack frame you want and you'll see the corresponding code

Comment: I added another possible solution here below. I'd like to receive a feedback from you, maybe you can try it. Thank you.

Comment: @superpuccio we usually use the SynchronizationContext for that, but yes, it's a perfectly valid solution

Answer (score 1):

According to the @KooKiz explanation and the @StephenCleary comment I found another possible solution. Since we have understood that the problem is here:

```
var window = view.CoreWindow;
```

we can cache the dispatcher saving it as an instance variable. Doing so, we avoid to access it at the same time of the timer:

```
namespace TryAccelerometer
{        
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Accelerometer acc;
        private DispatcherTimer timer;                
        private int numberAcc = 0;
        private int numberTimer = 0;
        private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

            acc = Accelerometer.GetDefault();                                    
            acc.ReadingChanged += acc_ReadingChanged;

            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();            
        }

        async void acc_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
        {            
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                numberAcc++;
            });
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            numberTimer++;            
            acc.ReportInterval = acc.ReportInterval++;
            //acc.ReadingChanged -= acc_ReadingChanged;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
    }
}
```

This way the deadlock doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I created this extension after having deadlock issues on WinRT, and it solved my problems (so far):

```cs
using global::Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using global::Windows.UI.Core;

public static class UIThread
{
    private static readonly CoreDispatcher Dispatcher;

    static DispatcherExt()
    {
        Dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
    }

    public static async Task Run(DispatchedHandler handler)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, handler);
    }
}
```

Usage

```cs
public async Task Foo()
{
    await UIThread.Run(() => { var test = 0; });
}
```